# Upgrading from sonar 3.4.1 to sonarqube 3.7.4

Tags: regex, checkstyle, sonarqube

I am working on an effort which tests sonar upgrade from 3.4.1 to 3.7.4 and some of our custom Regexp checkstyle rules are missing.

```
for ex:
 Regexp Multiline ISO 8859 check which comes from Checkstyle "checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.regexp.RegexpMultilineCheck_1395067207" 

RegexpMultiline += " (StringBuilder)
checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.regexp.RegexpMultilineCheck_1343391212
```

I am not sure if these are rule extensions of the existing checkstyle rules (like Regexp Singleline,Regexp Multiline etc.,) or they come from checkstyle usually and are deprecated in the current version of SonarQube.

I did look for a list of checkstyle rules which are deprecated however i couldn't find them.

thanks

Comment: The rules with `_<number>` at the end of their names were created by someone using the "[Copy Rule](http://www.sonarqube.org/sonar-2-3-in-screenshots/)" button on the *RegexpMultilineCheck* rule. So they exist only on your SonarQube instance. I would simply write down their configuration and recreate them after the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the list of deprecated checkstyle rules by selecting appropriate repository and Status ="deprecated" under My Quality profile. Some of rules were missing because the database was corrupted. Its all good.